# How to generate a plotly chart studio link with subplots

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to build a Dash application in python that prints out three charts on localhost:8050,
For example, here are three figures which are returned with dcc.Graph

```
    def funct(data, x_data, y_data ):
        line_fig = px.line(x=x_data, y=y_data, title="Trend Line")
        indi_fig = go.Indicator(value = len(data), title='Total Count')
        bar_fig = go.Bar(x=x_data, y=y_data)
    return dcc.Grapgh(figure=line_fig), dcc.Grapgh(figure=indi_fig), 
                      dcc.Grapgh(figure=bar_fig)
```

This works perfectly, however, I want to share it using chart studio,
after providing username and api key, I want the function to work like below

```
    import chart_studio.plotly as py

    def funct(data, x_data, y_data ):
        line_fig = px.line(x=x_data, y=y_data, title="Trend Line")
        indi_fig = go.Indicator(value = len(data), title='Total Count')
        bar_fig = go.Bar(x=x_data, y=y_data)
        final_grid = [line_fig, indi_fig, bar_fig]
    return py.plot(final_grid, auto_open=True) #creates charts in plotly public repo
```

This doesn't work though. I am able to successfully run it if I pass only one fig, for eg.,

```
    return py.plot(line_fig, auto_open=True)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something important, but not sure what. The reason for 3 different charts is just customization and the way they are displayed in browser. I have not mentioned it in the code here.

Comment: I have not checked this in my environment, but is it not necessary to assign to fig? `fig=py.plot(line_fig, auto_open=True); return fig`

Comment: I don't think so, because the individual chart seems to work perfectly. It's only when I'm using multiple figures under final_grid. Regardless, I tried using your solution too, but no luck.